# Restrict access to all AWS resources based on the specific tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Do we have a solution to write AWS IAM policy to restrict access to all AWS components based on their tag?

Right now, Our AWS's resources already had a specific tag for each application. We would like to let developers from each application access only their application by separate with the tag, which has been tagged to each resource.

I have googled and found [this solution](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restrict-ec2-iam/). This solution just suited for AWS EC2.
Can we extend the scope to cover all AWS's resources?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use policy like this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "<permissions>",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {"StringLike": {"<service-name>:ResourceTag/<Tag-name>": "<Tag-value"}}
    }]
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for your prompted reply. Because of we have a lot of AWS resources in control. Can we use wildcard (*) in `<service-name>`